# pip install doesn't work ('pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command) but py -m pip install -U works

Tags: python, pip

Using python on windows.
When I try to install new libraries using

```
pip install 'library name'
```

it throws an error saying 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

But instead when I use the code

```
py -m pip install -U 'library name'
```

it gives me a working result.

Why is this so? I'm quite a beginner at programming, so please be a little elaborate with your answers. Thank You!

```
enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: @AmaanK i have followed everything in the thread you posted. It's still throwing an error. And if pip is not in my path, why is it working when I use py -m pip install -U

Comment: Because Python can find the pip package, and with `py -m pip` you're running pip through the package. That's how it works. (I find using `py -m pip` (and similar things like `py -m venv` and other `py -m ...` commands) better to use; you're guaranteed it uses the command installed with that Python/`py`).

Comment: @Tim, could you please pass in a screenshot of you Path environment variable both the system and user one. The best choice for you would be to reinstall python while enabling the option add python to Path

Comment: also, please give us the path where python is installed

Comment: Does typing "python" in the console work?

Comment: yes typing python displays the python version. @AmaanK , path is C:\\Users\myname\...

Comment: @AmaanK my PATH variable is not going to help you, the PATH variable is very dependent on where you have installed things. Also, I don't use Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'pip' command to the system's PATH
Environment Variables-->System variables-->Path-->Edit Environment Variable-->New-->
Then add the path to your Python Scripts directory,